# Return RSS feed in .NET Core API

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, rss, atom-feed

How can I create service that returns RSS from .NET Core API Controller.

I've seen some articles using `Rss20FeedFormatter` but it's not supported in Core.

Found this library too https://github.com/dotnet/SyndicationFeedReaderWriter, but it doesn't tell anything about APIs and proper returning of the RSSFeed as XML with `rss` type.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As show in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38332687/4990859

Decided to use this https://github.com/shawnwildermuth/RssSyndication which easily parses the XML to string and return it inside `Content` with type `text/xml`;