# SyndicationFeed in Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, syndication-feed

I have a problem with SyndicationFeed in asp.net core. I know that hasn't been ported yet to the asp.net core but I also use full .net framework so I think it should works.

Here's my code where I have an error:

```
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
```

and here's my project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices": "1.1.0-beta-000002",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "System.Xml.ReaderWriter": "4.3.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "net461": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.ServiceModel": ""
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "appsettings.json",
      "ClientApp/dist",
      "node_modules",
      "Views",
      "web.config",
      "wwwroot"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod"
    ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "Travelingowe"
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'ServiceModel' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: You added the using right? Is there where the error is?

Comment: Yeah I've added using. Moreover if I run application and click yes on the warning message about compilation error it everything works. I think the problem is with Visual Studio and compilation proces

Comment: Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Answered here -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/37416801/228160

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right way to work with RSS in ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309440/right-way-to-work-with-rss-in-asp-net-core-1-0-rc2)

Answer (score 7):

**2019 update:** SyndicationFeed has been released as nuget targeting following platforms:

- .NETFramework 4.6.1
- .NETCoreApp 2.1
- .NETStandard 2.0

Nuget: [System.ServiceModel.Syndication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Syndication/)

Answer (score 5):

This was just released by Microsoft https://github.com/dotnet/SyndicationFeedReaderWriter/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Answer (score -2):

SyndicationFeed is not supported under .NET Core

Comment: Your answer has become outdated now. Please update it